# Is there any way to initialise a Document object with a resourceID

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am wondering if there is a any way to Initialize a document object with a resource ID so that I can pass that document object in the various functions that i've made for manipulating the document.
Right now I have to pass in the function the eTag and resourceId of the document.
I'm using C#.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource ID is generated by Google Docs when you create a new Document via the API or the Google Docs user interface. You cannot set your own ID.